# Express .use() callback gets called multiple times when using express.static()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to authenticate user and once authenticated I want to create a new user in my own database with the data provided by authentication server.

The problem I am facing is that this `createNewAccount()` gets called 3 times. I don't exactly know why but once I removed the `express.static('app/web')` call this no longer happens. Still I need that call to serve static content, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
expressApp.use('/console',requiresAuth(),express.static('app/web'), (req,res)=>{
    createNewAccount(req.oidc.user.email);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be additional requests to static files like favicon.ico, manifest.json etc.

so callback fires on each of them :)

Comment: Sooo.. is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Actually that was a stupid question on my part. I could just send a request from client to create the account instead.